# taglib jsf core not loading

Tags: java, jsp, jar, tomcat7

i am having problems getting the jsp to compile for tomcat 7. a normal jsp with no f: tags will work correctly. I have these jars in my lib folder. I am only missing a jar or anything else?

jars

```
/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
/lib/jsf-api-1.2.jar
/lib/jsp-api.jar
/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
/lib/myfaces-api-2.1.13.jar

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index2.jsp 
at line 12

9: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
10: <title>Insert title here</title>
11: <body>
12: <f:view>
13: 
14: </f:view>
15: </body>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.jav     a:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

 java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java     :1856)
org.apache.jsp.index2_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(index2_jsp.java:105)
org.apache.jsp.index2_jsp._jspService(index2_jsp.java:78)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
  note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 
logs.
```

JSP page

```
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.ForEach"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<body>
<f:view>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You put jsf-api and myfaces-api in the same project. And they're also in different versions. Choose the jar that you'll really need, jsf-api or myfaces-api, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer was that Tomcat7 just doesn't work well with Oracle Java 8. Installing the JDK7 and pointing to that JDK in catalina.sh solved all issues with JSPs not compiling.